# Append html in php variable how I check the empty if condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to check the empty condition of $values in php and I remove the  old variable next time on click the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' onclick='myfunction();' name='submit'>submit</button>
 <?php 
   $values ='<p id="id"></p>';
   echo $values;
      //Here I need to check empty condition or else any other suggestion is there

     ?>
 <script>
    function myfunction() {
        package_id='1212';
        packagename='airline';
        var pakage_value= package_id+","+packagename;
        $('#id').append(pakage_value);

      }
 </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You're question is very unclear. Why would you need to validate the variable you just defined and set? Btw, why do you have a button with the type submit without anything to submit?

Comment: button is onclick function and get the values append in php varibles.please run and check

Comment: All your PHP does is setting a variable which you then echo. This all happens in the back end. When that's done, the result (all HTML and JS) is sent to the browser, which renders all HTML. When a user then clicks the button (which should be type "button"), you append some data to the `<p>`-tag. At this point, PHP is long gone. So, when a user have clicked the button and the data has been appended, what is it you actually want to happen? Remember that your `<p>`-tag has _no_ connection to anything PHP at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IN PHP**

```
 if(isset($values)){
    echo $values;
 }
```

**IN js**

```
if(typeOf(values) != 'undefined'){
    console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: thanks i need to remove in the next click in javascript

Answer (score 0):

USE jquery

```
var id_content = $("#id").html();   //get this element`s content

    if(id_content.lenght){            //judge content lenght 
        $("#id").html('');            //clear 
    }else{
          myfunction();               //add
    }
```

Comment: If you have alternative solutions, add them to the same answer.

Comment: sorry,i have new  alternative solutions,in next answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' onclick='click_function();' name='submit'>submit</button>
 <p id="id"></p> <script>

    function click_function(){
        var id_content = $("#id").html();  
        console.log(id_content.lenght);
        if(id_content!=''){            //judge content lenght 
            $("#id").html('');            //clear 
        }else{
              myfunction();               //add
        }
    }


    function myfunction() {
        package_id='1212';
        packagename='airline';
        var pakage_value= package_id+","+packagename;
        $('#id').append(pakage_value);

      }
 </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```